# Datagridview backcolor does not work on the first load

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a method in my form's load event that bind a datagridview. When the datagridview is binded, I modify some **backcolor** rows.

Before the binding I use `Me.SuspendLayout()` and when it's finish I use `Me.ResumeLayout`.

When my form load for the first time, all the rows use the `defaultCellStyle`. However, when I reload it by an event on a comboBox, it works as I expect (some rows have the modified backcolor). I tried to programmatically change the selectedIndex of my comboBox but it does not work either.

I tried to remove layout methods but it does not work too. Can someone give me advises ?

By the way, I'm developping in VB.NET (Visual Studio 2010).

**EDIT :**

```
Private Sub frm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    loadDTGV()
    Me.ResumeLayout()
    myCombo.SelectedIndex = 1
End Sub


Private Sub loadDTGV()
    Dim dtBindSource As New BindingSource()

    Dim lst As SortedBindingList.SortedBindingList(Of myClass)
    lst = _DAO.getData()
    dtBindSource.DataSource = lst
    dtgv.DataSource = dtBindSource

    If dtgv.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        colorRows()
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub colorRows()
    Dim grayStyle As New DataGridViewCellStyle
    grayStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray

    For i = 0 To dtg.Rows.Count - 1
        If dtg.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = "TEST" Then
            dtg.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle = grayStyle
        End If
    Next
End Sub


Public Sub changeIndex() Handles myCMB.SelectedIndexChanged
    loadDTGV()
End Sub
```

Comment: could you please give [mcve]

Comment: @Mederic I edited my post

Comment: My guess would be that on first load your datagrid has no rows, so ColorRows doesn't get called. Does lst actually contain any rows when first loaded?

Comment: @Slugsie In the first load, my datagridview contains 1105 rows.

Comment: Does it actually hit the line 'dtg.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle = grayStyle'?

Comment: @Slugsie For the 2nd row and a lot of others

Answer (score 6):

I found some articles about same problems and it seems that there is an issue with the `datagridview` control (we cannot change the color cells until the form has been shown). Methods runs and events are fired but they will not change colors.

To resolve my problem, I placed my method to color rows in the `DataBindingComplete` event. It works very well now.

Comment: I met the same problem too. If I programmatically filled DGV according to the dataTable and then change the color, no matter it is shown or not, the color works well. But if I use `DGV.DataSource = dataTable` then change the color, the color will not shown expectedly unless the DGV is already shown, until I execute these AGAIN AFTER the DGV's first shown. But the `DataBindingComplete` event works very well. This is very unreasonable, because the order of the steps are virtually the same! BTY, this case will happen when we change 2 GDV in 2 tabPage. this is not hypothetical.

Answer (score 0):

Add coloring metod into form_shown event.